# What are some ways to measure the growth of a visual designer?

Tags: graphic-design

If someone starts out as a junior designer and keeps practicing, what are some benchmarks to show they have progressed as a better designer?

Comment: Are you talking about a visual designer in terms of an interaction designer who is concerned with the visual display of information? Or are you talking about a graphic designer? The latter is off topic - you'd have better luck on [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I agree, this needs more information to get at the root of the question.

Comment: Visual designer could apply to either of those. I think the question is equally valid here as it is on Graphic Design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking for within the realms of UX, then [UX Design Practice Verticals](http://www.methodbrain.com/dsia/resource/ux-design-practice-verticals.cfm) can be a good measurement for you.

Its a grid, made of eight columns standing for main domains in UX, and six grades of depthness going from practical to strategical areas of practise. It was introduced at UXmatter article [The T-Model and Strategies for Hiring IA Practitioners](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2011/11/the-t-model-and-strategies-for-hiring-ia-practitioners-part-2.php), but explained solely for Information Architects. Nevertheless, it matches Visual Design either.

I like this approach, because it has well thought categories and shows the differences as well as overlaps of each specialist in the field of "Computer Design". And it gives a sort of guidance, where to grow and what to leave aside.

Comment: Thanks for the resource! It definitely points me in the right direction.